# Elm: How to use data from one HTTP request in subsequent requests

Tags: elm

I am new to Elm and just read the docs (https://guide.elm-lang.org/). I am modifying an example from there and playing around.
What I want to do is to hit an endpoint which will give me a list of IDs. Later I want to hit another endpoint with each of these IDs and display the results.

https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json -
This endpoint has a list of IDs.

[https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/[ID].json](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/%5BID%5D.json) -
This endpoint will give the details of the story of given ID.

With what I have till now, I can get the list of all IDs separately and I can get each story separately (hard-coded ID) and display them. But what I am trying achieve here is to

- get the list of IDs (500 of them) from endpoint 1
- get first 5 of the stories by hitting endpoint 2
- have a "load more" button which will load 5 more and so on

I am not sure how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire the second request when you handle the response from the first endpoint. Something like:

```
type Msg
    = GotIds (Result Http.Error (List Int))
    | GotStory (Result Http.Error (String))


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model,  Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotIds result ->          
            case result of
                Ok (first::rest) -> 
                    ({ model | ids = first::rest }, getStory first)
                Ok _ ->
                    (model, Cmd.none)
                Err _ ->
                    ({ model | story = "ERROR"}, Cmd.none)
        GotStory result ->    
            ({model | story = Result.withDefault "None" result}, Cmd.none)
```

If you want to fire multiple Cmd at the same time, you can use [Cmd.batch](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#batch)

[Here is an Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/9syNMz5SGhRa1) that gets the ids from the first request and then fetches the title for the first ID.

You will want to create a custom type and [decoder](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json.Decode) for each post.

For posterity's sake, here is all of the code from the Ellie:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Http
import Json.Decode exposing (Decoder, field, int, list, string )

type alias Model =
    { ids : List Int 
    , story : String
    }


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { ids = [] 
    , story = "None"
    }


type Msg
    = GotIds (Result Http.Error (List Int))
    | GotStory (Result Http.Error (String))


update : Msg -> Model -> (Model,  Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotIds result ->          
            case result of
                Ok (first::rest) -> 
                    ({ model | ids = first::rest }, getStory first)
                Ok [] ->
                    (model, Cmd.none)
                Err _ ->
                    ({ model | story = "ERROR"}, Cmd.none)
        GotStory result ->    
            ({model | story = Result.withDefault "None" result}, Cmd.none)


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ text model.story
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = (\_ -> Sub.none)
        }
        
init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags =
    (initialModel, getIds)
        
getIds : Cmd Msg
getIds =
  Http.get
    { url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotIds (list int)
    }

getStory : Int ->  Cmd Msg
getStory id =
  Http.get
    { url = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" ++ String.fromInt id ++ ".json"
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotStory (field "title" string)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean I should request for the ids each time I want to get stories? Is there a way to store the ids and loop through and request stories each time user clicks "load more"? So I will request for ids once on page load and then use that data for other requests.

Comment: @Varshith the ids are stored on the model.  `{ model | ids = first::rest }`.  This is how Elm manages state: all state is on the model.  
  
You will want to add another variant to Msg to handle the user clicking "load more".

Comment: When using "remoteData" package, its different. How to use "WebData ( List a )" as "List a" to be able to use "(first::rest)" or other List operations?

Comment: take a look at the type annotation for [RemoteData](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/remotedata/latest/RemoteData#RemoteData).  You will want to use a case statement to determine if the result is a Success.  This will look a lot like the case statement over Result above.